# Oracle Java 8 x64 for Linux and RandomSource

Tags: java, security, tomcat, ubuntu, startup

I really thought that after about 200 or more tomcat installs on various platforms, I am ready for any kind of challenge but this one is tricky.

I created a vanilla Ubunutu 14_04 image and installed Java 8 TGZ from oracle on that system. Furthermore I added a tomcat 8 to the game. Then I started the vanilla server install.

Soon after hanging on deploying the default apps shipped with tomcat, I wondered whats happening there and did some threaddumps. This one was the lousy thread who prevented tomcat from starting:

```
"localhost-startStop-1" #15 daemon prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f37c8004800 nid=0x4d6 runnable [0x00007f37b38b3000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:246)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator$URLSeedGenerator.getSeedBytes(SeedGenerator.java:539)
    at sun.security.provider.SeedGenerator.generateSeed(SeedGenerator.java:144)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom$SeederHolder.<clinit>(SecureRandom.java:192)
    at sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.engineNextBytes(SecureRandom.java:210)
    - locked <0x00000000f06e6ce8> (a sun.security.provider.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.nextBytes(SecureRandom.java:457)
    - locked <0x00000000f06e71c0> (a java.security.SecureRandom)
    at java.security.SecureRandom.next(SecureRandom.java:480)
    at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom(SessionIdGeneratorBase.java:234)
```

After more google & friends i discovered that the `SeedGenerator` shipped with the JDK is the source of my problem. Interestingly sometimes the SeedGenerator came back after several minutes and sometimes it just hung (running out of entropy? ... checked via `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail`) . After more research I found out that a config variable in `$JAVA_HOME$/lib/security/java.security` called `securerandom.source` defines what the source for Random is. In my case, or better in the oracle JDK 8 install for linux, it was `/dev/random`. I am not a Linux expert (I am a java developer) but what I understood is that `/dev/random` can run out of entropy (whatever this means) but perhaps it means at some point it cant generate any more random numbers). I switched to `/dev/urandom` and everything was fine with my tomcat.

Then i checked how other JDK installs look like on my other various server, which were a wild mix of OpenJDK and older Oracle JDK installs. At least OpenJDK always used `/dev/urandom` what might be the answer, why I have never had the problem before.

**Now to my question**: Is it sane from Oracle to rely on `/dev/random` when there can be corner cases where the OS cant produce any more numbers? I mean servers like Tomcat and many others rely on `SeedGenerator` from the JDK and debugging this kind of error is really advanced. Took me 2 hours to get to the point where i am now.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can resolve the issue because I have never had this problem but using Tomcat native library http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/apr.html 
may help you skip this issue, plus some performance enhancement since it uses a native library for random numbers,... 
please let me know if it helped

Comment: http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/ explains /dev/random and /dev/urandom very well and also shares my view with using /dev/random when used by... Lets say... Apllication Servers because of its blocking nature.

Comment: You [saw this bug](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093) right? Says it is fixed in JDK 8. Maybe it is a bug in Tomcat if it isn't using newer implementation of `SecureRandom`...You could ask on the Tomcat mailing list.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're really asking. Is it sane? Well, it's not insane, but it would be considerably better if they used /dev/urandom on linux. I don't get what more there is to say. Why's the bounty here?

Comment: I recommend to install haveged on all Linux servers. It keeps filling up the entropy pool and reduces hangs related to `/dev/random`. It is not a good idea to switch to /dev/urandom if not even the minimum entropy for seeding PRNGs is available on the system.

Comment: BTW: Tomcat wraps as far as I know the random number seeding and adds some timeout. The message is descrbed for example here: https://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/HowTo/FasterStartUp#Entropy_Source Not sure why it did not time-out in your case, it is certainly the same method.

Answer (score 5):

I think the answer relies in this link for WebLogic support: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13209_01/wlcp/wlss30/configwlss/jvmrand.html
where they mention that "random" is more secure

and also in the Oracle bug comment (already mentioned by David): http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4705093

with particular regard to this part:

> Because SHA1PRNG is a MessageDigest-based PRNG, it historically has always used /dev/random for initial seeding if seed data has not been provided by the application.  Since all future values depend on the existing state of the MessageDigest, it's important to start with a strong initial seed.
>
> Changing that behavior was troubling to the original developer.  So he did created a new SecureRandom impl called NativePRNG, which does respect the java.security.egd value.
>
> If you call:
>
> - new SecureRandom() on Linux and the default values are used, it will read from /dev/urandom and not block.  (By default on Solaris, the PKCS11 SecureRandom is used, and also calls into /dev/urandom.)
> - SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG") and do not specify a seed, *OR* new SecureRandom() but have specified an alternate java.security.egd besides "file:/dev/urandom", it will use the SHA1PRNG which calls into /dev/random and may potentially block.
> - SecureRandom.getInstance("NativePRNG"), it will depend on what java.security.egd is pointing to.

Comment: Q: "Is it sane [for] Oracle to rely on /dev/random?" ... A: "Changing that behavior was troubling". It's not fully sane, in my opinion, but it is at least understandable that they (Sun, Oracle, whatever ... a big corp with lots of big corp customers) didn't want to change defaults in a way that could theoretically have security implications for people who had relied on those defaults in the past.

Answer (score 0):

> what I understood is that /dev/random can run out of entropy (whatever this means) but perhaps it means at some point it cant generate any more random numbers).

It can *temporarily* run out of entropy and block until it gathers enough to dispense more. The JVM only needs a little to seed a `SecureRandom` instance.

How long it takes depends on how noisy your system is and how the kernel gathers entropy.

> Is it sane from Oracle to rely on /dev/random when there can be corner cases where the OS cant produce any more numbers?

The lack of entropy can be problematic on embedded systems or in VMs on first boot which come with a very deterministic image, have few sources of entropy that can be harvested compared to real PCs and no RDRAND instruction or similar for the kernel to harvest for entropy pool initialization.

Insufficient randomness can be catastrophic for key generation and other cryptographic algorithms, e.g. [DSA is quite sensitive to the quality of your entropy source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Signature_Algorithm#Sensitivity).

So yes, it is quite sane to rather wait than having a compromised system.

To quote from [Mining Your Ps and Qs: Detection of Widespread Weak Keys in Network Devices](https://factorable.net/weakkeys12.extended.pdf) by N.Heninger et al.

> To understand why these problem are occurring, we manually
>   investigated hundreds of the vulnerable hosts, which were
>   representative of the most commonly repeated keys  as  well  as  each 
>   of  the  private  keys  we  obtained (Section
>    3.2 ). Nearly all served information identifying them as headless or embedded systems, including routers, server management cards,
>   firewalls, and other network de- vices. Such devices typically
>   generate keys automatically on first boot, and may have limited
>   entropy sources com- pared to traditional PCs.
>
> Furthermore, when we
>   examined clusters of hosts that shared a key or factor, in nearly all
>   cases these appeared to be linked by a manufacturer or device model. 
>   These observations lead us to conclude that the problems are caused by
>   specific defective implementations that generate keys without having
>   collected sufficient entropy.

If you have an external source of entropy and root privileges you can [push additional entropy into the pool and increment its counter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17118705/1362755) (i think `rngd` can do this for you). Just writing to `/dev/random` will add your entropy to the pool but not increase the counter.

For VMs there also are [virtualization drivers](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/03/09/red-hat-enterprise-linux-virtual-machines-access-to-random-numbers-made-easy/) to get entropy from the host.

Pointing the jvm to a hardware RNG dev (/dev/hwrng, /dev/misc/hw_random or something like that) may also be an option, if they're available.