# Unable to get db connection after Java 8 upgrade

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, ojdbc

I have recently upgraded an application from java 1.7 to 1.8. Rest of the libraries versions remains unchanged. I am getting the following error after the upgrade:

```
DEBUG 2015-11-12 09:55:12 BasicResourcePool         An exception occurred while acquiring a poolable resource. Will retry.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at oracle.net.jndi.JndiAttrs.getAttrs(JndiAttrs.java:207)
    at oracle.net.resolver.AddrResolution.<init>(AddrResolution.java:198)
    at oracle.net.ns.NSProtocol.connect(NSProtocol.java:219)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.connect(T4CConnection.java:1102)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:320)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:546)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:236)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Hibernate configurations:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldaps://XXXX,cn=OOOO,dc=WWW</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">YYYY</property>
        <property name="hibernate.statement_cache.size">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">ZZZZZ</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">1800</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">YYYY</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Related Libraries used:

- ojdbc6 11.2.0.3.0
- hibernate 3.1

**Problem:**
The dependencies contained 2 hibernate version 3.1 and 3.0 and ojdbc6 and ojdbc7. (used `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose` to got dependency tree)

**Solution:**
Excluded the other versions of hibernate and ojdbc from the dependencies.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>****</groupId>
                <artifactId>****</artifactId>
                <version>****</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
                        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: maybe related if you use a linux distribution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26227344/oracle-java-8-x64-for-linux-and-randomsource

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As i can see from the [Oracle FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_02), the jdbc driver you are using is not compatible with the Database Version and JDK8.

> What are the various supported Oracle database version vs JDBC compliant versions vs JDK version supported? 
>   [image]

I think this must be your problem. Maybe if you used ojdbc7.jar might help (not sure about this cause I haven't tested it yet - MOST PROBABLY THIS WOULD FAIL)

Comment: I am using JDK8, ojdbc7 12.1 and Oracle Db version is 12.1 but still getting the same problem.

Comment: I am using JDK8, ojdbc7 and Oracle 11.2 , still getting nullpointer errros